# Creating a function that takes a list or integer as argument (Python)

Tags: python, list, function, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a function that gives the average of either a list of numbers or just integers as variables. So far I have:

```
def average(*args):
    if type(args) is list:
        for x in args:
            print sum(x) / float(len(x))
    else:
        for x in args:
            args = list(args)
            print sum(x) / float(len(x))
```

When I input a list, like

```
average([1, 3, 5, 2])
```

it works great. But when I enter in

```
average(1, 3, 5, 2)
```

it gives "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable".
I've checked other questions but none of the solutions seem to work. I've tried to check if it's a list with type() and isinstance() but whenever I get one of them to work, the other throws out an error.

Comment: Why are you attempting to `sum(x)` and `len(x)` passing a simple `int`? Furthermore, try to add `print(type(args))` and you will discover that is a `tuple` not a `list`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

args is a tuple so check if `args[0]` is a list the sum the contents of `args[0]`, if just ints are passed in  just sum args:

```
def average(*args):
    if isinstance(args[0],list):
        print(sum(args[0]) / float(len(args[0])))
    else:
        print (sum(args) / float(len(args)))


In [2]: average(1, 3, 5, 2)
2.75

In [3]: average([1, 3, 5, 2])
2.75
```

If you want to accept tuples,use `collections.Iterable`:

```
from collections import Iterable
def average(*args):
    if isinstance(args[0],Iterable):
        print(sum(args[0]) / float(len(args[0])))
    else:
        print (sum(args) / float(len(args)))

In [5]: average([1, 3, 5, 2])
2.75

In [6]: average(1, 3, 5, 2)
2.75

In [7]: average((1, 3, 5, 2))
2.75
```

Answer (score 1):

the second `print sum(x) / float(len(x))` calls `len()` on x, which is an integer.

I think you mean something like:

```
  else:
        print sum(args) / float(len(args))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Demo on [repl.it](http://repl.it/2Zv)

```
def average(*args):
    if type(args) is tuple:
        r = 0
        for x in args:
            for y in x:
                r += y
        print r / float(len(x))
    else:
        print sum(args) / float(len(args))

average([2, 3, 8, 1, 9])
```

Comment: When I do it this way, it accepts the "average()" argument but not the "average([])" list argument.

Comment: Try to modify to read: `if type(args) is tuple:` rather than `if type(args) is list:` :)

Comment: Lol now it works for "average([])" and not "average()". This has been the bane of my past four hours.

Answer (score 0):

The if portion in your code i.e. `if type(args) is list:` is never going to be executed. Because, whenever non-keyword arguments are passed to a function using `*args`, the value received as `args` is always a tuple. So `type(args) is list` is always going to be `False`. What needs to be done is iterate through the arguments passed through `*args` and check if the type of argument, if it's list then you have passed a list `i.e. average([1,3,5,7])` else it will be integer when integers are passed `i.e. average(1,3,5,7)`. So following piece of code will work :-

```
def average(*args):
    for x in args:
        if type(x) == list:
            # List is passed
            return sum(x) / float(len(x))
    # Assuming inputs passed restricted to list and numbers
    # Numbers are passed as argument
    return sum(args) / float(len(args))
```

Here this will provide you the output for both types of input :-

```
>>> average([1,3,5,7])
4.0
>>> average(1,3,5,7)
4.0
```